# NHibernate WHERE Subquery Equals/GreaterThan/LessThan

Tags: nhibernate

I am wanting to know how to restrict the results in the outer query based on the value of a subquery in NHibernate.

The sql would look something like:

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    ParentTable p
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(c.Id) FROM ChildTable c WHERE c.ParentId = p.Id) > n
```

I've got as far as:

```
Parent parentAlias = null;
Child childAlias = null;
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => parentAlias);
var subquery = Session.QueryOver(() => childAlias).Where(childAlias.Parent.Id == parentAlias.Id);
query.WithSubquery...
```

But can't seem to get much further - unless I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out. Here is a pseudo example:

```
outerQuery.WithSubquery.WhereValue(int).Lt(subquery);
```

Will execute as in SQL as

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  OuterTable
WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM InnerTable WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent parentAlias = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Child>().Where(child.Parent.Id == parentAlias.Id);
var query = session.QueryOver(() => parentAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(subquery)
    .List();
```

Comment: Hi Firo - firstly sorry for the delay in responding. Secondly that's helpful but it doesn't answer my question completely. I need to limit the results in the outer query based on the row count of the subquery..